# Selenium testing and emma code coverage

Tags: java, unit-testing, selenium-rc

Is there a way to get the code coverage when running selenium testing? The problem here is selenium is invoking the UI directly instead of the real source which UI component calling. So any solution please? I have try the eclemma plugin also but no luck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emma and Cobetura can both instrument your classes to carry out coverage reporting (I've used Cobetura to do this and not EMMA) Emma carries out static analysis plus analysis of runtime events and I prefer it nowadays.

Clover can be pointed at the JVM to tell you coverage too - they explain how to do this.

Sonar's product also allows measuring of dynamic tests - they're feature is described on their site.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the same thing, getting a Java runtime code coverage report for selenium tests. Do you have any pros/cons for the different tools (Emma, Cobetura, Clover, Selenium) that would help choose the right (i.e. best suited for the task) one?

Answer (score 0):

are you using selenium remote control with java? http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/

I think when the code is comoiled correctly it should work, because at some point of time the underlying methods will be called.